# перебор массива reduce

Tags: javascript

Я очень хочу разобраться с reduce, но опыта не хватает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно переписать данный метод с его использованием?

```
let arr = [{
    "otklplansnachalagoda202110": 454554,
    "otklplantekuschmesyac202111": -76356,
    "vypolnplantekuschmesyac20216": 0,
    "viddohoda4": "Налоги",
},
{
    "otklplansnachalagoda202110": -188689,
    "otklplantekuschmesyac202111": -172763,
    "vypolnplantekuschmesyac20216": 0,
    "viddohoda4": "Налоги",
}]

const keys = Object.keys(arr[0])
arr = arr.map(elem => {
  const f = {}
  Object.values(elem).forEach((el, index) => { el !== null && el !== '' ? f[keys[index]] = el.toString() : f[keys[index]] = el})
  return f 
})
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы все значения объектов преоразовать в строку, исключая нулевые значения и пустые строки и вернуть массив с исправленными значениями. Код выше - рабочий, просто хочется найти решение именно с reduce.

Comment: По-моему, код выдает результат, не совсем соответствующий заданию - нули также преобразуются в строки (или под нулевым значением понимается именно null?). А reduce при обработке массива выcчитывает ОДНО значение. Какой же смысл его использовать если требуется вернуть массив?

Comment: _"исключая нулевые значения"_ - приведенное решение не исключает их. Более подходящее решение цикл + map. `reduce` тут ну совсем ни к месту.

Comment: @AndreySemykin Извратиться то можно и с reduce. Другое дело, что тут требуется два прохода. Где reduce то хочется вкрутить? И почему два цикла не устраивают (for of, for in)? Непонятно.

Comment: @AndreySemykin, там если проверку на null не ставить, то мне выдается null как "null", просто в этом массиве нет таких значений, но данная проверка отрабатывает как нужно

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey то есть не стоит заморачиваться, так в целом ок?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, Я же не писал, что нельзя использовать reduce. Но какой смысл? :)

Comment: @e.mesheraykova Я рекомендую вам упросить и сделать два цикла `for...of` и `for...in`

Comment: @AndreySemykin Да, смысла нету. Любой reduce в этой задаче превращается в forEach с избыточным кодом

Comment: @AndreySemykin, конечный массив и будет этим _одним значением_

Comment: @Grundy Но это же все равно будет лишнее действие? Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: спасибо за комментарии и предложенные варианты!

Comment: @AndreySemykin, какое лишнее действие?

Comment: @Grundy Я имел в виду, добавляется лишнее действие к первоначальному коду  с map - требуется еще запихивать в массив обработанный объект. В случае с map объект и так оказывается в результирующем массиве. :)

Comment: @AndreySemykin, обычно map никто и не меняет на reduce. В вопросе стандартный код, с объектом и forEach, который является самописным reduce

Answer (score 0):

Можно быстро перевести так и не заморачиваться

```js
let arr = [{
    "otklplansnachalagoda202110": 454554,
    "otklplantekuschmesyac202111": -76356,
    "vypolnplantekuschmesyac20216": 0,
    "viddohoda4": "Налоги",
},
{
    "otklplansnachalagoda202110": -188689,
    "otklplantekuschmesyac202111": -172763,
    "vypolnplantekuschmesyac20216": 0,
    "viddohoda4": "Налоги",
}]

const keys = Object.keys(arr[0])
arr = arr.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  const f = {};
  Object.values(elem).forEach((el, index) => { el !== null && el !== '' ? f[keys[index]] = el.toString() : f[keys[index]] = el})
  acc.push(f);
  return acc;
}, [])


console.log(arr)
```

можно и по другому это сделать

```js
let arr = [{
        "otklplansnachalagoda202110": 454554,
        "otklplantekuschmesyac202111": -76356,
        "vypolnplantekuschmesyac20216": 0,
        "viddohoda4": "Налоги",
    },
    {
        "otklplansnachalagoda202110": -188689,
        "otklplantekuschmesyac202111": -172763,
        "vypolnplantekuschmesyac20216": 0,
        "viddohoda4": "Налоги",
    }]

function objectToString(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (typeof obj[item] === 'object') {
      acc[item] = objectToString(obj[item]);
    } else {
       acc[item] = obj[item] !== null? '' + obj[item]: obj[item];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});;
}

function arrayObjectToString(array) {
  return array.reduce( (acc, item)=> {
    acc.push(objectToString(item));
    return acc;
  } ,  []); 
}


    console.log(arrayObjectToString(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не самая подходящая задача для освоения reduce. Тут просто нечего аккумулировать.

Поскольку вариант с reduce уже предложен, я просто приведу вариант решения вашей задачи без reduce и других методов:

```js
let arr = [{
    "otklplansnachalagoda202110": 454554,
    "otklplantekuschmesyac202111": -76356,
    "vypolnplantekuschmesyac20216": 0,
    "viddohoda4": "Налоги",
  },
  {
    "otklplansnachalagoda202110": -188689,
    "otklplantekuschmesyac202111": -172763,
    "vypolnplantekuschmesyac20216": 0,
    "viddohoda4": null,
  }
]

for (let obj of arr) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    if(obj[k] !== null) obj[k] = obj[k].toString();
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

**UPD**
Вижу не всем по вкусу такая наглость, поэтому double-reduce вариант:

```
let keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);

arr = arr.reduce((a, av) => (
  a.push(
    Object.values(av).reduce((o, ov, i) => (
      o[keys[i]] = ov === null ? ov : '' + ov, o
    ), {})
  ), a
), []);
```

Теперь совесть чиста.